# Jenkins EC2 Plugin Script Approval

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I just updated my Jenkins from 2.79 to 2.86

It seems to add new security fixes but it broke the EC2-Plugin

Indeed, now everytime the plugin is trying to launch a slave agent, I got an error:

"Launching agent" "ERROR: script not yet approved for use"

But the script to be approve via the Script Approval page is dynamic, containing temporary information

Did someone find how to solve the issue?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I partially found a fix by unchecking the `Connect by SSH Process` in the EC2 configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn on sandbox mode. Whole-script-approval mode really should not be used any more.

While Used In a script, nothing else, only checkout, load the script and function call

Refer [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42023)

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue while launching the slave agent via the SSH client process. As we were not able to quickly solve this, we've decided to downgrade Jenkins to version 2.84.

Answer (score 0):

I also downgraded to 2.84 as I could not figure out how to enable sandbox mode.
Created new JIRA with Jenkins team.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47979

Answer (score 0):

- go to manage jenkins
- got to IN-process script approval
- approve pending scripts
- and then launch the agent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).